# add multiple text boxes and drop down by click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(

                $("<input/>", {name: 'text[]', type: 'text', id: 'filediv'}), 
                $("<select/>", {name: 'option[]', type: 'option', id: 'filediv'}).append('<option>select</option>','<option value="1">Yes</option>','<option value="2">No</option>'),
                $("<input/>", {name: 'text[]', type: 'text', id: 'filediv'}),  

                $("<br/><br/>")
                ));
    });
```

I have used this script to add multiple text  boxes but the problem is we want last text box while choosing NO option other wise it should be disable

Comment: NO option selection from dynamic created dropdown?

Comment: Dude, where is the full stop in sentence? However, can you please share the HTML you want to repeat.

So, that I can give you an appropriate script for your question...

Comment: lol @BlueSuiter maybe he's sentence not finished?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like:

```
$('#add_more').prev().remove('<div/>');
```

If your code is using .append(), one option would be to keep a reference to the element you're appending, and use that to remove it later.

```
var $appendElem = $('<div>some appended element</div>');

$appendElem.appendTo('#add_more');
```

Then you can remove it via the same reference.

```
$appendElem.remove();
// or
$appendElem.detach();​​​​​​​​​
```